# Crash in SDWebImageManager imageDownloader:didFinishWithImage:

Tags: objective-c, ios, sdwebimage

We recently released our app to the appstore, and almost immediately got a few crashes in SDWebImageManager imageDownloader:didFinishWithImage:
The top of the stacks look like:

```
0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x33c28c98 objc_msgSend + 16
1 CoreFoundation 0x308f0571 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 25
2 Ourcode 0x0001d98f -SDWebImageManager imageDownloader:didFinishWithImage:
3 CoreFoundation 0x308f0571 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 25
4 Ourcode 0x0001cb03 -SDWebImageDownloader connectionDidFinishLoading:
```

We have the latest SD code that does a retain on the delegate inside this function.
As long as our delegate is created properly, I don't see how we get into this situation. It appears to me that the delgate the performSelector on has been freed. But SDWebImageManager reatains the delegate.

The relevant code for imageDownloader:didFinishWithImage: is:

```
- (void)imageDownloader:(SDWebImageDownloader *)downloader didFinishWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    [downloader retain];
    SDWebImageOptions options = [[downloader.userInfo objectForKey:@"options"] intValue];

     // Notify all the downloadDelegates with this downloader
    for (NSInteger idx = (NSInteger)[downloaders count] - 1; idx >= 0; idx--)
    {
        NSUInteger uidx = (NSUInteger)idx;
        SDWebImageDownloader *aDownloader = [downloaders objectAtIndex:uidx];
        if (aDownloader == downloader)
        {
            id<SDWebImageManagerDelegate> delegate = [[[downloadDelegates objectAtIndex:uidx] retain] autorelease];

            if (image)
            {
                if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(webImageManager:didFinishWithImage:)])
                {
                    [delegate performSelector:@selector(webImageManager:didFinishWithImage:) withObject:self withObject:image];
               }
           }
```